# How to read and parse data in Java with HandleMessage method?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, arduino, android-bluetooth

I am building an android app that will be able to read values from a load sensor. The load sensor is connected to a LCD to display the values of weight applied to the sensor and an Arduino board. I am simply building this app to get the weight values from the LCD/load sensor. I am using HC-06 Bluetooth module, and I am able to connect/pair with this device successfully. The 'MainActivity' activity has a 'get data' button to read the data from the load sensor but anytime It is pressed the app freezes. I have been told by the author of the following tutorial that I need to write some 'Handler' method. I have made an attempt with no luck.

I've been following this tutorial but I'm stuck on reading data

https://wingoodharry.wordpress.com/2014/04/15/android-sendreceive-data-with-arduino-using-bluetooth-part-2/

Here is my code :

```
package com.proj.splate;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.UUID;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.HandlerThread;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.os.Message;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  Button btnscan;
  TextView txtArduino, txtString, txtStringLength, calorie;
  Handler bluetoothIn;

  final int handlerState = 0;                        //used to identify handler message
  private BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = null;
  private BluetoothSocket btSocket; //= null;
  private StringBuilder recDataString = new StringBuilder();

  private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;

  // SPP UUID service - this should work for most devices
  private static final UUID BTMODULEUUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

  // String for MAC address
  private static String address;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Link the buttons and textViews to respective views                
    btnscan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scanBtn);             
    txtString = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtString); 
    txtStringLength = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.testView1); 

    bluetoothIn = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
            if (msg.what == handlerState) { 
                String readMessage = (String) msg.obj; 
                recDataString.append(readMessage);
                int endOfLineIndex = recDataString.indexOf("~"); 
                if (endOfLineIndex > 0) { 
                    String dataInPrint = recDataString.substring(0, endOfLineIndex); 
                    txtString.setText("Data Received = " + dataInPrint);                
                    int dataLength = dataInPrint.length();  
                    txtStringLength.setText("String Length = " + String.valueOf(dataLength));

                    if (recDataString.charAt(0) == '#') 
                    {
                        //get sensor value from string between indices 1-20
                        String weight = recDataString.substring(1, 20);
                        //update the textviews with sensor values
                        calorie.setText(weight + "kg");

                    }
                    recDataString.delete(0, recDataString.length());                    
                   // strIncom =" ";
                    dataInPrint = " ";
                }            
            }
        }
    };

    btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(); // get Bluetooth adapter
    checkBTState();  

  // Set up onClick listeners for button to scan for data
    btnscan.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
        mConnectedThread.write("0");
      }
    });
}

  private BluetoothSocket createBluetoothSocket(BluetoothDevice device) throws IOException {

      return  device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(BTMODULEUUID);
      //creates secure outgoing connecetion with BT device using UUID
  }

  @Override
  public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    //Get MAC address from DeviceListActivity via intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    //Get the MAC address from the DeviceListActivty via EXTRA
    address = intent.getStringExtra(DeviceListActivity.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS);

    //create device and set the MAC address
    BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);

    try {
        btSocket = createBluetoothSocket(device);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Socket creation failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }  
    // Establish the Bluetooth socket connection.
    try 
    {
      btSocket.connect();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      try 
      {
        btSocket.close();
      } catch (IOException e2) 
      {
        //insert code to deal with this 
      }
    } 
    mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(btSocket);
    mConnectedThread.start();

    //I send a character when resuming.beginning transmission to check device is connected
    //If it is not an exception will be thrown in the write method and finish() will be called
    mConnectedThread.write("x");
  }

  @Override
  public void onPause() 
  {
    super.onPause();
    try
    {
    //Don't leave Bluetooth sockets open when leaving activity
      btSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e2) {
        //insert code to deal with this 
    }
  }

 //Checks that the Android device Bluetooth is available and prompts to be turned on if off 
  private void checkBTState() {

    if(btAdapter==null) { 
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Device does not support bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
      if (btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
      } else {
        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 1);
      }
    }
  }

  //create new class for connect thread
  private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        //creation of the connect thread
        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            btSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            try {
                //Create I/O streams for connection
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) { }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  
            int bytes; 

            // Keep looping to listen for received messages
            while (true) {
                try {
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                    bluetoothIn.obtainMessage(handlerState, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget(); 
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        //write method
        public void write(String input) {
            byte[] msgBuffer = input.getBytes();//converts entered String into bytes
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(msgBuffer);//write bytes over BT connection via outstream
            } catch (IOException e) {  
                //if you cannot write, close the application
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Connection Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();

              }
            }

        public class BluetoothInHandler extends Handler{
            private Looper sLooper = null;

            private Handler mWorkerThreadHandler;

            final int handlerState = 0;                        //used to identify handler message


            protected class WorkerArgs {
                Handler handler;
                String input;
                String output;
            }


            public BluetoothInHandler() {
                super();
                synchronized (BluetoothInHandler.class) {
                    if (sLooper == null) {
                        HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("AsyncWorker");
                        thread.start();

                        sLooper = thread.getLooper();
                    }
                }
                mWorkerThreadHandler = new WorkerHandler(sLooper);
            }

            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                if (msg.what == handlerState) {
                    WorkerArgs args = (WorkerArgs) msg.obj;
                    String readMessage = args.output;
                    //your job;
                } else {
                    super.handleMessage(msg);
                }
            }

            public void write(String input) {
                WorkerArgs args = new WorkerArgs();
                args.handler = this;
                args.input = input;
                Message message = mWorkerThreadHandler.obtainMessage(handlerState);
                message.obj = args;
                mWorkerThreadHandler.sendMessage(message);
            }

            protected class WorkerHandler extends Handler {
                public WorkerHandler(Looper looper) {
                    super(looper);
                }



                @Override
                public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                    if (msg.what == handlerState) {
                        WorkerArgs args = (WorkerArgs) msg.obj;
                        byte[] buffer;
                        //the code here run in a thread, not in the ui thread
                        //do your job like:
                        byte[] bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);


                        args.output = new String(bytes);
                        Message message = args.handler.obtainMessage(handlerState);
                        message.obj = args;
                        message.sendToTarget();
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        }//ConnectedThread End              

}
```

Here is my Arduino Code:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

int led = 13;
int button = 12;

LiquidCrystal lcd(9, 8, 4, 5, 6, 7);
// Pins used for inputs and outputs********************************************************

float sensorValue1;
float containerValue;
char inbyte = 0;
int flag;
const int numReadings = 50;
int readings[numReadings];
int index = 0;
int total = 0;
int average = 0;



//*******************************************************************************************

void setup()
{

  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
  Serial.begin(9600);

  for (int thisReading = 0; thisReading < numReadings; thisReading++)
  {
      readings[thisReading] = 0;
  }

  lcd.begin(16, 2); //change to 16, 2 for smaller 16x2 screens
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("hello, world!");
  delay (1000);
  lcd.clear();
  delay (500);

}

void loop() 
{
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH); 
  readSensor2();    //DONE


  printLCD();       //DONE
  return;

 sendAndroidValues();

  //when serial values have been received this will be true
  if (Serial.available() > 0)
  {
    inbyte = Serial.read();
    if (inbyte == '0')
    {
      //LED off
      digitalWrite(led, LOW);
    }
    if (inbyte == '1')
    {
      //LED on
      digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
    }
  }

  //delay by 2s. Meaning we will be sent values every 2s approx
  //also means that it can take up to 2 seconds to change LED state
  delay(2000);


void readSensor2()
{
  total = total - readings[index];

  readings[index] = analogRead(A0);

  total = total + readings[index];

  index = index + 1;

  if (index >= numReadings)
  {
     index = 0;
  }

  average = total / numReadings;



   //sensorValue1 = (analogRead(A0) - 330)* i;
   //delay(200);


   Serial.println(average);
   delay(100);


   if( digitalRead(button) == HIGH && flag == 1)
  {
    flag = 0;
    containerValue = 0; 

  }
  else if (digitalRead(button) == HIGH && flag != 1)
 {
  flag = 1;                        //when the button is pressed the initially sesnsor 
    containerValue = sensorValue1;  
    delay(10);
  }

  //Serial.println(digitalRead(button));
   delay (1000);

}

//sends the values from the sensor over serial to BT module
void sendAndroidValues()
 {
  //puts # before the values so our app knows what to do with the data
 Serial.print('#');
  //for loop cycles through 4 sensors and sends values via serial
  Serial.print(sensorValue1);
  Serial.print('+');
    //technically not needed but I prefer to break up data values
    //so they are easier to see when debugging
 Serial.print('~'); //used as an end of transmission character - used in app for string length
 Serial.println();
 delay(5000);        //added a delay to eliminate missed transmissions
}

void printLCD()
{
  lcd.setCursor(4, 0);
  lcd.print("   GRAMS    ");
  lcd.setCursor(4, 1);
  lcd.print(sensorValue1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is much of a problem, since it doesn't look like you're doing a ton of work in your handleMessage(Message msg) method, but your Handler is still being created on the main thread.  To use a Handler to process background messages, you'll need to pass it a separate Looper.  An easy way to to do this would be to use the [HandlerThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html) class to provide your Looper.

Once you do this, however, you'll need to post results back to your UI thread from your `handleMessage(Message msg)` since you can't modify UI elements (or use Toasts, see your "write" method) from threads other than the main thread (See Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable runnable)).

Also, you're still using your "ConnectedThread" object as an object by how you're calling your methods from within your onClickListener...so it's not really doing what you're intending it to do in that regard.  To verify this, use Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper() to see which thread is currently executing.  I'd advise more towards the Handler solution suggested above, and posting Runnables for execution.

Lastly, since you're ConnectedThread runs continously in a while(true) loop without pauses, this could be flooding your handler potentially as well.